# Display all data from 1 column in database and display to a single textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want display all data from 1 column in database and display to a single textbox and separated by comma.

Here is my code:

```
strsql = "Select value from lookup_table where group_id = " & desc_id
cmd = New SqlCommand(strsql, conn)        
Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
conn.Open()
Dim sms As New DataTable
Adapter.Fill(sms)
For i As Integer = 0 To sms.Columns.Count - 1
Label1.Text = sms.Rows(0)(i).ToString + ","
 Next
```

Comment: What does not work in the code snippet in your question?

Comment: Also note that you are overwriting the label's text instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 1):

try that code

it shows all data in column 0

```
    strSql = "Select value from lookup_table where group_id = " & desc_id
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(DbCOnn)
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(strSql, conn)
    Dim Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    conn.Open()
    Dim sms As New DataTable
    Adapter.Fill(sms)
    Label1.Text = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To sms.Rows.Count - 1
        Label1.Text += sms.Rows(i)(0).ToString + ","
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the data but overwriting it.

**Remove this line**

```
Label1.Text = sms.Rows(0)(i).ToString + ","
```

**Replace it with this**

```
 Label1.Text = Label1.text + "," + sms.Rows(0)(i).ToString
```